# How to set equal heights for child divs with CSS

Tags: css, html, overflow

There is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/only_dimon/6fgyy/
There is css:

```
.row {
width: 600px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
}
.news {
width: 190px;
margin-left: 15px;
border: solid 1px #ccc;
background: #ddd;
float: left;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 10px;
height: 100%;
}
.news:first-child {
 margin-left: 0;   
}
```

JQuery defines div's height without no problems. Why children div can't get 100% height of parent? Red that the height of div with auto height is non-set value. Why is that so?
In example, overflow:hidden make the div "row" to get the max height of childs. And it visualy changed width of itself.

Please, explain me.

Tnx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Read the specification of [**CSS height property**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property).

> The **percentage** is calculated with respect to the height of the
> generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing
> block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content
> height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value
> computes to 'auto'. A percentage height on the root element is
> relative to the initial containing block.
>
> *Note: For absolutely positioned elements whose containing block is based on a block-level
> element, the percentage is calculated with respect to the height of
> the padding box of that element. This is a change from CSS1, where the
> percentage was always calculated with respect to the content box of
> the parent element.*

So you should either set the children's `position` to `absolute` (which will ignore the `float` setting and will need explicit horizontal positioning for each child) or specify the `height` of the container explicitly such as:

```
.row {
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here is your [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/onury/6fgyy/5/).
Also, check out [this approach](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks) about "**Equal Height Columns**".

Comment: Thanks. Setting the height to the container it's not the solution for me. Just like absolute positioning or fixes with additional markup.

Comment: So i'm used to do it with JQuery.
But I don't get: Why the percentage working like that? Like it was written in specification.

Answer (score 1):

Height inheritance needs to go all the way up the tree.

Try:

```
body, html { height:100% }

.row {
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height:100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Hm, and all the three blocks got window 100% height, but need the height of .row